# Android Local VPN - filter URLs

Tags: android, firewall, vpn

I'm trying to implement a local VPN service in my app to register the entrance to the address: example.com
Something like firewall app for Android.

As an example I used: https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN

Regarding this example I'm able to set breakpoint in the process loop and debug packages.
But only what I get is: source/destination IP, HOST, protocol and other:

```
W/VPNRunnable: IP4Header{version=4, IHL=5, typeOfService=0, totalLength=40, identificationAndFlagsAndFragmentOffset=884883456, TTL=64, protocol=6:TCP, headerChecksum=14993, sourceAddress=10.0.0.2, destinationAddress=172.217.20.166, hostNameDesc=waw02s07-in-f166.1e100.net, hostNameSour=waw02s07-in-f166.1e100.net}
```

My question: **It is possible to determine what is the full URL of the request**?
URL like: http://example.com/test/page?a=111&b=222

Comment: Had any luck resolving this? I am facing same issue so.

Comment: From what I have determined, it is impossible.
You can get only ip/hostname.